# Indexing synthetic partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos container using a [synthetic partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys) `/pk`, where the value is only used for partitioning and never used in a query clause. Is there any reason not to exclude this path from indexing, given that the value is provided as the partition key with all operations? It seems like it should be excluded from indexing by definition, but not sure if partitioning and indexing somehow interact.

Comment: You should by all means not do this as by definition then all of your queries would then be fan outs which you really should try to avoid. Is there any reason why you would want to do this?

Comment: They would fan out even when the partition key is provided in the read/query operation? Just exploring this in the process of excluding unneeded fields to reduce write RUs. By excluding pk I see a small but decent decrease in create cost.

Comment: No, if you include the partition key it will not fan out. But you still need to keep the /pk in the index. In fact, because so many people are unclear on this. We are soon going to start indexing it automatically, even if you exclude it.

Comment: Very good to know, thanks for clarifying Mark. Please feel free to move comment to answer so we can mark this for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always include the partition key in your queries because queries without the partition key in the where clause will be fan outs which you really should try to avoid.

It is also recommended to keep the partition key in the index. There are quite a few people confused by this. We are soon going to start indexing it automatically, even if you exclude it so people don't suffer from not indexing it.